# Pytesseract : Unable to extract date from image

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, text-extraction

I am  trying to extract date from an image [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqLso.jpg).The date is located at the bottom right corner, so I have also tried cropping the image first and then trying to extract date, but none of them seem to work.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("datepic.jpg")
date = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,config='--psm 10 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
date

##cropping the image to get only the date part
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("datepic.jpg")
left =320
right = 460
top = 330
bottom = 350
m1 = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
plt.imshow(m1)
date = pytesseract.image_to_string(m1, config='-psm 9 tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
date
```

I have played with the psm value also, but none of them gave desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Using the information the date is located at the bottom right corner, we can estimate its position. Next, we can upsample and perform color-segmentation of the image for an accurate recognition, to make the digits more visible for both human-eye and tesseract. Finally, we apply adaptive-threshold to extract and OCR the letters.

- 1. **Upsampling and performing color-segmentation**: We load the image, crop the the date part by estimating its coordinates. Upsample (using [`cv2.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html)) the cropped region to make its visible. To perform color-segmentation, we need to convert the cropped region to HSV format, define lower/upper ranges and perform color segmentation using [`cv2.inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) to obtain a binary mask.
- 2. **Extracting date part**: After obtaining binary mask we will use it to remove the background and separate date part from the rest of the image using [`cv2.bitwise_and`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html). Arithmetic operation `and` is highly useful for defining roi in hsv colored images.
- 3. **Applying adaptive-threshold** After extracting the date from the image, we will see a dense-yellow area which make it impossible to read from the roi. Therefore [`simple-thresholding methods`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html) are not useful. We will use [`cv2.adaptiveThreshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) to make the features detectable by the tesseract. Note that `blockSize` and `C` parameters can vary from image-to-image.
- 4. **Perform OCR**: After isolating only the features from roi, we don't need to use any [`page-segmentation-mode`](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method). We simply use `image_to_string` without any configuration and get the result.

---

Steps

- Estimating the date position:

  - [image]
  - If you divide the width into 5 equal-distinct part, you need last two-part and the height of the image slightly up from the bottom:
  - [image]
  - If we upsample the image:
  - [image]
  - Now the image is readable and clear. However the yellow dense area is a blocking artifact for OCR.
  - ```py
    img = cv2.imread("QqLso.jpg")
    (h, w) = img.shape[:2]
    crp = img[h-30:h, int((3*w)/5):w]
    crp = cv2.resize(crp, (0, 0), fx=5, fy=5)
    ```
- Mask generated from color-segmentation

  - [image]
  - The idea is to remove the area which does not contain date information.
  - ```py
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(crp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lwr = np.array([0, 102, 0])
    upr = np.array([179, 255, 255])
    msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upr)
    ```
- Extacting date part using bitwise_and

  - [image]
  - Now we have the date-information with artifact blocking the day and month data.
  - ```py
    res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(crp, crp, mask=msk)
    ```
- Applying adaptive-threshold

  - [image]
  - The artifact is partially gone and the image is suitable for extracting OCR.
  - ```py
    crp_img = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    crp_gry = cv2.cvtColor(crp_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(crp_gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                                cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 31, 9)
    ```
- Result of tesseract-ocr

  - ```
    01/02/2021.14:213
    ```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Estimate the position
img = cv2.imread("QqLso.jpg")
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
crp = img[h-30:h, int((3*w)/5):w]

# Up-sample
crp = cv2.resize(crp, (0, 0), fx=5, fy=5)

# Create binary mask
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(crp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lwr = np.array([0, 102, 0])
upr = np.array([179, 255, 255])
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upr)

# Remove background
res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(crp, crp, mask=msk)

# Adaptive-threshold
crp_img = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
crp_gry = cv2.cvtColor(crp_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(crp_gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 31, 9)

# OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)

# display
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

To find lower and upper boundaries of the mask, you may find useful: [HSV-Threshold-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469394/opencv-choosing-hsv-thresholds-for-color-filtering)

Comment: Thanks @Ahx.I am getting this output  ym

0110212021 14: 21}. I can process this to get the date.In the absence of highlighted part on date, how can we get rid of background?. Also I noticed the, the output of tesseract is very sensitive to last two params of adaptive threshold.Is there a way to automatically find out these values(without trial and error as this needs to be done on multilple images)

Comment: What is your pytesseract version? Please make sure it is the current version. You are right about adaptive threshold, but this is an image-processing solution. If you want to find automatically, then you should use deep-learning ocr.

Comment: Once I have all the images, I can check if this approach works well for all them.But pytesseract also has an option to use LSTM.I guess what I will need is custom deeplearning OCR, if this does not work.Thanks @Ahx

Comment: How would this example be changed if the original image did NOT have the yellow marker covering the date? As in, what steps would be changed or removed? I'd like to extract text from an image, just like the original poster, but my images don't have marks over the dates.

Comment: This answer is an example of in-range thresholding. If you have a normal image, you can use global thresholding. If you have a slightly distorted image you can use adaptive thresholding. For more read from the documentation: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html