# how get digits recognize from electric meter with minimum libs?

Tags: python, opencv, kivy, ocr

I am developing an application for android with python3 and kivy to which I want to add a functionality to automatically recognize the digits of the electric meter from the camera of the device, for which I have found a variety of solutions using opencv
with numpy, mahotas, pytesseract, scipy, scikit_learn among other packages.

Trying:

```
https://github.com/VAUTPL/NUMBERS_DETECTION_1
https://github.com/spidgorny/energy-monitor
```

But, I need to be able to achieve this efficiently with the minimum of libraries because when generating the apk with buildozer I must add all the libraries used and this generates a file too big in size, just to add this functionality.

What do you recommend to achieve this goal with the minimum number of libraries?

the idea:
[non-digital](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV43a.jpg)

EDIT 1:
I need extract digits from meters digital and non-digital :
[digital meter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enwv2.jpg)

Comment: You can use ABBYY Mobile Capture. It would cost you ~20-30 Mb with good optimization.

Comment: but that is online service and I need pay? I'm from cuba. I need a offline and free solution xDD , you know... but how integrate  ABBYY Mobile Capture with python kivy? thanks for your suggest

Comment: Sorry, I know no good solutions for free OCR

Answer (score 1):

One approach is combining image-processing methods with [`pytesseract`](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/). Python-tesseract is an optical character recognition (OCR) tool for python For the current example, you need to perform color-segmentation to get the binary-mask. Next, you need to use the binary-mask to remove the background, then read the OCR digits using tesseract.

- 1. **Performing color-segmentation**: We convert the loaded image to the HSV format define lower/upper ranges and perform color segmentation using [`cv2.inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) to obtain a binary mask.
- 2. **Extracting digits:** After obtaining binary mask we will use it to remove the background and separate digit part from the rest of the image using [`cv2.bitwise_and`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html). Arithmetic operation and is highly useful for defining roi in hsv colored images.
- 3. **OCR with tesseract:** We will set page-segmentation-mode to 6 ([see all](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method)) to get an accurate output.

---

- Color segmentation for getting binary mask

  - [image]
  - ```py
    lwr = np.array([43, 0, 71])
    upr = np.array([103, 255, 130])
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upr)
    ```
- Extracting digit using binary mask

  - [image]
  - ```py
    krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
    dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=5)
    res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)
    ```
- OCR

  - ```
    15753 .
    ```
  - ```py
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, config="--psm 6 digits")
    print(txt)
    ```
  - If you want to remove `.` or any other non-alpha character, you could do
  - ```
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, config="--psm 6 digits")
    print(''.join(t for t in txt if t.isalnum()))
    ```
  - Result will be `15753`

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("input.png")

# Color-segmentation to get binary mask
lwr = np.array([43, 0, 71])
upr = np.array([103, 255, 130])
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upr)
cv2.imwrite("/Users/ahx/Desktop/msk.png", msk)

# Extract digits
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=5)
res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)
cv2.imwrite("/Users/ahx/Desktop/res.png", res)

# Displaying digits and OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, config="--psm 6 digits")
print(''.join(t for t in txt if t.isalnum()))
cv2.imshow("res", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

To find lower and upper boundaries of the mask, you may find useful: [HSV-Threshold-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469394/opencv-choosing-hsv-thresholds-for-color-filtering)
*

---

Update:

---

If the same technique is applied to the digital-meter numbers, result will be

- [image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This technique would also work for a digital meter numbers? I edit post with image...

Comment: I've updated the answer see the answer under Update-1

Comment: It does not work the same for me, anyway I need suggestions to see if this can be achieved with less libraries or smaller packages so as not to make the python bubble of my apk too big
. thank

Answer (score 0):

I try take picture from webcam but the result is not the same.

```
print("PRESS 'c' FOR TAKE THE PICTURE")
camara=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    (grabacion, img) = camara.read()
    imagen = cv2.resize(img, (200, 120))
    cv2.rectangle(imagen, (xf, rois), (xf+197, rois+50), (0, 255, 0), 2)cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("CAMARA",imagen)
    tecla=cv2.waitKey(1)
    if tecla==ord('c'):
        image=img
        break
    if tecla==ord('x'):
        break

# Color-segmentation to get binary mask
lwr = np.array([43, 0, 71])
upr = np.array([103, 255, 130])
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upr)
cv2.imwrite("/home/barcelo/projects-kivy/ocr1/msk.png", msk)

# Extract digits
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=5)
res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)
cv2.imwrite("/home/barcelo/projects-kivy/ocr1/res.png", res)

# Displaying digits and OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, config="--psm 6 digits")
print(''.join(t for t in txt if t.isalnum()))
cv2.imshow("res", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osEad.png)

Answer (score 0):

You maye use digits detection. And use the display rules of meter to avoid mistake charactors. Finally, you will get right value.