# Masking problems in 6 digit recognition using OpenCV with lighted meter

Tags: python, opencv, digits, image-thresholding, imutils

I am trying to recognize six digits from a meter using python-OpenCV. It's surprising how incredibly hard it is to set morphological operations working in the right way, given the time I have spent adjusting the focus/distance of my raspberry pi camera to the meter screen and I even have bought a separate led lamp to have as much uniform light as possible. This is a template image
[image]
and I've tried using and adjusting the code from these two sources: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217089/how-get-digits-recognize-from-electric-meter-with-minimum-libs) and [enter link description here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/) reproduced below without any progress. I got stuck right at the start when setting the thresholding options. Thank you in advance for any help.

```py
# Code 1
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")

# Color-segmentation to get binary mask
lwr = np.array([43, 0, 71])
upr = np.array([103, 255, 130])
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upr)
cv2.imwrite("msk.png", msk)

# Extract digits
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=5)
res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)
cv2.imwrite("res.png", res)

# Displaying digits and OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(res, config="--psm 6 digits")
print(''.join(t for t in txt if t.isalnum()))
cv2.imshow("res", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```py
# code 2
# https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/
# import the necessary packages
# from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

# define the dictionary of digit segments so we can identify
# each digit on the thermostat
DIGITS_LOOKUP = {
        (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1): 0,
        (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1): 1,
        (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1): 2,
        (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 3,
        (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0): 4,
        (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1): 5,
        (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1): 6,
        (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 7,
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1): 8,
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 9
}

images = 'test.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(images, 1)
# pre-process the image by resizing it, converting it to
# graycale, blurring it, and computing an edge map
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
# gray = cv2.medianBlur(blurred, 1)

# threshold the warped image, then apply a series of morphological
# operations to cleanup the thresholded image
(T, thresh) = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255,
                       cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

mask = np.zeros((image.shape[0] + 2, image.shape[1] + 2), np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(thresh, mask, (0, 0), 0)
cv2.floodFill(thresh, mask, (image.shape[1]-1, 0), 0)
cv2.floodFill(thresh, mask, (round(image.shape[1]/2.4), 0), 0)
cv2.floodFill(thresh, mask, (image.shape[1]//2, 0), 0)
cv2.floodFill(thresh, mask, (0, image.shape[0]-1), 0)
cv2.floodFill(thresh, mask, (image.shape[1]-1, image.shape[0]-1), 0)

kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 13))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

# cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
# cv2.destroyAllWindows()


# find contours in the thresholded image, then initialize the
# digit contours lists
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
digitCnts = []
# loop over the digit area candidates
for c in cnts:
        # compute the bounding box of the contour
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        # if the contour is sufficiently large, it must be a digit
        if w <= 300 and (h >= 130 and h <= 300):
            digitCnts.append(c)
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

# cv2.imshow('image', image)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
# cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# sort the contours from left-to-right, then initialize the
# actual digits themselves
digitCnts = contours.sort_contours(digitCnts, method="left-to-right")[0]
digits = []

clao = 0
# loop over each of the digits
for c in digitCnts:
        clao = clao + 1
        # extract the digit ROI
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        roi = thresh[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        # compute the width and height of each of the 7 segments
        # we are going to examine
        (roiH, roiW) = roi.shape
        (dW, dH) = (int(roiW * 0.25), int(roiH * 0.15))
        dHC = int(roiH * 0.05)
        # define the set of 7 segments
        segments = [
                ((0, 0), (w, dH)),                           # top
                ((0, 0), (dW, h // 2)),                      # top-left
                ((w - dW, 0), (w, h // 2)),                  # top-right
                ((0, (h // 2) - dHC), (w, (h // 2) + dHC)),  # center
                ((0, h // 2), (dW, h)),                      # bottom-left
                ((w - dW, h // 2), (w, h)),                  # bottom-right
                ((0, h - dH), (w, h))                        # bottom
        ]
        on = [0] * len(segments)

        # loop over the segments
        for (i, ((xA, yA), (xB, yB))) in enumerate(segments):
                #  extract the segment ROI, count the total number of
                #  thresholded pixels in the segment, and then compute
                #  the area of the segment
                segROI = roi[yA:yB, xA:xB]
                total = cv2.countNonZero(segROI)
                area = (xB - xA) * (yB - yA)
                # if the total number of non-zero pixels is greater than
                # 50% of the area, mark the segment as "on"
                if clao == 1:
                        if total / float(area) > 0.34:
                                if area < 1500:
                                        on = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
                                else:
                                        on[i] = 1
                else:
                        if total / float(area) > 0.39:
                                if area < 1500:
                                        on = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
                                else:
                                        on[i] = 1

        # lookup the digit and draw it on the image
        digit = DIGITS_LOOKUP.get(tuple(on)) or DIGITS_LOOKUP[
                min(DIGITS_LOOKUP.keys(), key=lambda key: norm(np.array(key)-np.array(on)))]
        # digit = DIGITS_LOOKUP[tuple(on)]
        digits.append(digit)
        # print(digits)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.putText(image, str(digit), (x - 10, y - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# display the digits
print(digits)
cv2.imshow("Input", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Update**

Apologies for my late reply but I have been quite busy with work.

I have captured 22 images throughout the day and used @fmw42 code (with some amendments) to apply thresholding and morphological operations. I am making the images available [here](https://upload.disroot.org/r/qE4QbUVR#beoHi6ILp6APrj61TePhp1weBKBT3K04aHfWAzu/daw=) and the code that I am using is available below. Overall the performance is quite robust, although 1s and sometimes 8s get mixed up with 2s. I am happy to accept a code that provides improved performance. Note: I think that one problem is that the vertical lines of the numbers are slightly slanted? Thank you in advance.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from imutils import contours
import imutils
import os

# define the dictionary of digit segments so we can identify
# each digit on the thermostat
DIGITS_LOOKUP = {
        (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1): 0,
        (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1): 1,
        (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1): 2,
        (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 3,
        (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0): 4,
        (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1): 5,
        (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1): 6,
        (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 7,
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1): 8,
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 9
}

path_of_the_directory = "/home/myusername/mypathdirectory"
ext = ('.jpg')
for files in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):
    if files.endswith(ext):
        # load image
        print(files)
        img = cv2.imread(path_of_the_directory+files)

        # convert to grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # blur
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (0,0), sigmaX=51, sigmaY=51)

        # divide
        divide = cv2.divide(gray, blur, scale=255)

        # threshold  
        thresh = cv2.threshold(divide, 235, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

        # apply morphology
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (41,41))
        morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (41,41))
        morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        morph = cv2.bitwise_not(morph)  # reverse
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1, 70))
        morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

        # write result to disk
        cv2.imwrite("digits_division.jpg", divide)
        cv2.imwrite("digits_threshold.jpg", thresh)
        cv2.imwrite("digits_morph.jpg", morph)

        # display it
        cv2.imshow("divide", divide)
        cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
        cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        # find contours in the thresholded image, then initialize the
        # digit contours lists
        cnts = cv2.findContours(morph.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        digitCnts = []

        # loop over the digit area candidates
        for c in cnts:
                # compute the bounding box of the contour
                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                # if the contour is sufficiently large, it must be a digit
                if w >= 60 and (h >= 300 and h <= 800):
                    digitCnts.append(c)
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        cv2.imshow('image', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        # sort the contours from left-to-right, then initialize the
        # actual digits themselves
        digitCnts = contours.sort_contours(digitCnts, method="left-to-right")[0]
        digits = []

        clao = 0
        # loop over each of the digits
        for c in digitCnts:
                clao = clao + 1
                # extract the digit ROI
                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                roi = morph[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                # compute the width and height of each of the 7 segments
                # we are going to examine
                (roiH, roiW) = roi.shape
                (dW, dH) = (int(roiW * 0.25), int(roiH * 0.15))
                dHC = int(roiH * 0.05)
                # define the set of 7 segments
                segments = [
                        ((0, 0), (w, dH)),                           # top
                        ((0, 0), (dW, h // 2)),                      # top-left
                        ((w - dW, 0), (w, h // 2)),                  # top-right
                        ((0, (h // 2) - dHC), (w, (h // 2) + dHC)),  # center
                        ((0, h // 2), (dW, h)),                      # bottom-left
                        ((w - dW, h // 2), (w, h)),                  # bottom-right
                        ((0, h - dH), (w, h))                        # bottom
                ]
                on = [0] * len(segments)
                
                # loop over the segments
                for (i, ((xA, yA), (xB, yB))) in enumerate(segments):
                        #  extract the segment ROI, count the total number of
                        #  thresholded pixels in the segment, and then compute
                        #  the area of the segment
                        segROI = roi[yA:yB, xA:xB]
                        total = cv2.countNonZero(segROI)
                        area = (xB - xA) * (yB - yA)
                        # if the total number of non-zero pixels is greater than
                        # 50% of the area, mark the segment as "on"
                        if clao == 1:
                                if total / float(area) > 0.34:
                                        if area < 1500:
                                                on = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
                                        else:
                                                on[i] = 1
                        else:
                                if total / float(area) > 0.42:
                                        if area < 1500:
                                                on = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
                                        else:
                                                on[i] = 1
                                                
                # lookup the digit andq draw it on the image
                digit = DIGITS_LOOKUP.get(tuple(on)) or DIGITS_LOOKUP[
                        min(DIGITS_LOOKUP.keys(), key=lambda key: norm(np.array(key)-np.array(on)))]
                # digit = DIGITS_LOOKUP[tuple(on)]
                digits.append(digit)
                # print(digits)
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
                cv2.putText(img, str(digit), (x - 10, y - 10),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # display the digits
        print(digits)
        cv2.imshow("Input", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()        
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will help you using division normalization in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("digits.jpg")

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (0,0), sigmaX=51, sigmaY=51)

# divide
divide = cv2.divide(gray, blur, scale=255)

# threshold  
thresh = cv2.threshold(divide, 235, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("digits_division.jpg", divide)
cv2.imwrite("digits_threshold.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("digits_morph.jpg", morph)

# display it
cv2.imshow("divide", divide)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Division normalized image:

[image]

Thresholded image:

[image]

Morphology processed image:

[image]

You can then clean up further by getting contours and removing small contours and very long horizontal contours.

Comment: Thanks. I will test this soon and report back if there are any issues. I shall use multiple images/numbers but under the same light and resolution to see if your code is robust.

Comment: I've used portion of your code against a larger dataset of images and the performance is quite good (see my updated answer above).

Answer (score 2):

The key to getting this working is cleaning the image up which I have done to a good enough level to get it to work. I've done this using scikit image library.

I then look at certain squares on the image and take an average reading from that area.
On the right hand-side image I've marked some of the locations with red squares.

[image]

My script I used to get this result:

```py
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import imageio.v3 as iio
import skimage.filters as skif
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from skimage.restoration import denoise_bilateral

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.cm as cm

threshold = 125
digit_loc = [1600, 1300, 1000, 730, 420, 155]
size = 20
x_mid = 80
x_right = 160
y_top = 130
y_mt = 250
y_mid = 380
y_bm = 520
y_bot = 630


def img_with_threshold(orig_img):
    block_size = 255
    local_thresh = skif.threshold_local(
        orig_img,
        block_size,
        method="mean",
    )
    binary_local = orig_img > local_thresh

    u8_val = img_as_ubyte(binary_local)
    return u8_val


def image_denoise(orig_img):
    return denoise_bilateral(orig_img, win_size=10, bins=10, )


def plot_imgs(orig_img, mod_img):
    # Display the image
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 8), sharex=True, sharey=True)
    ax = axes.ravel()
    ax[0].imshow(orig_img, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
    ax[1].imshow(mod_img, cmap=cm.Greys_r)
    # Create a Rectangle patch
    for x_loc in digit_loc:
        rect1 = Rectangle((x_loc + x_mid, y_top), size, size, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        rect2 = Rectangle((x_loc, y_mt), size, size, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        rect3 = Rectangle((x_loc + x_right, y_mt), size, size, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        rect4 = Rectangle((x_loc + x_mid, y_mid), size, size, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        rect5 = Rectangle((x_loc, y_bm), size, size, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        rect6 = Rectangle((x_loc + x_right, y_bm), size, size, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        rect7 = Rectangle((x_loc + x_mid, y_bot), size, size, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')

        # Add the patch to the Axes
        ax[1].add_patch(rect1)
        ax[1].add_patch(rect2)
        ax[1].add_patch(rect3)
        ax[1].add_patch(rect4)
        ax[1].add_patch(rect5)
        ax[1].add_patch(rect6)
        ax[1].add_patch(rect7)

    plt.show()


def seg_to_digit(segments, location):
    digit_values = {0b1110111: 0,
                    0b0010010: 1,
                    0b1011101: 2,
                    0b1011011: 3,
                    0b0111010: 4,
                    0b1101011: 5,
                    0b1101111: 6,
                    0b1110010: 7,
                    0b1111111: 8,
                    0b1111011: 9,
                    }
    result = int("".join(["1" if i < threshold else "0" for i in segments]), 2)
    # print("score:", result)
    return digit_values.get(result, 0) * 10 ** location


def get_digit(location, mod_img):
    """
      a
    b  c
     d
    e  f
     g
    """
    x_loc = digit_loc[location]
    m_loc = (x_loc + x_mid, x_loc + x_mid + size)
    l_loc = (x_loc, x_loc + size)
    r_loc = (x_loc + x_right, x_loc + x_right + size)
    seg_a = np.average(mod_img[y_top:y_top + size, m_loc[0]:m_loc[1]])
    seg_b = np.average(mod_img[y_mt:y_mt + size, l_loc[0]:l_loc[1]])
    seg_c = np.average(mod_img[y_mt:y_mt + size, r_loc[0]:r_loc[1]])
    seg_d = np.average(mod_img[y_mid:y_mid + size, m_loc[0]:m_loc[1]])
    seg_e = np.average(mod_img[y_bm:y_bm + size, l_loc[0]:l_loc[1]])
    seg_f = np.average(mod_img[y_bm:y_bm + size, r_loc[0]:r_loc[1]])
    seg_g = np.average(mod_img[y_bot:y_bot + size, m_loc[0]:m_loc[1]])
    segments = [seg_a, seg_b, seg_c, seg_d, seg_e, seg_f, seg_g]
    # print(f"x loc: {x_loc}, digit index: {location}, segment values: {segments}")
    # create an integer from the bits
    # print('value:', result)
    return seg_to_digit(segments, location)


def main():
    data_dir = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath('data')
    meter_img = data_dir.joinpath('meter_test.jpg')
    img = iio.imread(meter_img)
    gray_img = img_as_ubyte(rgb2gray(img))
    img_result = image_denoise(gray_img)
    img_result1 = img_with_threshold(img_result)
    reading = 0
    for dig_loc in range(6):
        reading += get_digit(dig_loc, img_result1)
        print(f"{reading:>21}")
    print("Final reading:", reading)

    plot_imgs(gray_img, img_result1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This gave the following output:

```bash
                    7
                   77
                  677
                 4677
                24677
               924677
Final reading: 924677
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test this soon and report back if there are any issues. I shall use multiple images/numbers but under the same light and resolution to see if your code is robust.

Comment: I'm having some difficulties installing `iio` and so I was not able to test your code against my images. I'll let you know as soon as I get it working