# How to accurately detect brown/black/grey/white on this picture with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, colors, hsv

I first used HoughCircles to find the centers of each circles, but then i realized  that i would also need to know the colors of corresponding circles found, so i tried an other approach ( see below).

Note: circles will be placed randomly, no no hardcoding.

Here's whats the image looks like :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Problem:**

Very hard to get accurate HSV value to correctly detect the colors in the title, plus the image quality is not the best. I think the middle circle in those pucks is to help us distinguish them but as most have a light blue circle in it, im not sure how it helps haha.

**What i tried:**

**1.**

I used openCV trackbar, to get the approximate lower and upper bound for each color ( except those mentioned) which are really hard to get).

**2.**

I apply the mask on the picture and then find the center of circles with moments.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    
    img = cv2.imread('Photos/lastBoard.png')
    frame_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #red color
    lower_values = np.array([0,123,40])
    upper_values = np.array([5,255,114])
    
    mask = cv2.inRange(frame_hsv, lower_values, upper_values)
    
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for c in contours:
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        if M["m00"] != 0:
            #####
            (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
            center = (int(x),int(y))
            
            radius = int(radius)
            cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    
            cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
            #this condition is just to tell to detect in that area of the image only
            if cX > 500 and radius >8:
                cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 2, (0,255,0), -1)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**What i need help with**

Finding the brown, black, white and grey color is really hard and my approach doesn't seem very accurate. Is there a better way for me to do this ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible way to do it, it still uses the `HSV` color space, you have to get the `HSV` range values right. Look up the `RGB -> HSV` equivalent values for your target colors. You could definitely benefit from some **pre-processing** to clean up a little bit better your masks. You can also implement a **contour filter**, because the blobs of interest you are looking for (the pucks) have very **distinct properties**, for example, aspect ratio, area and, of course, circularity. I propose the following steps:

1. Get `HSV` values for each target puck you are looking for
2. Define the `upper` and `lower` range values
3. Threshold the `HSV` image to get a binary mask
4. Apply an **area filter** to get rid of small noise
5. Apply some morphology (`Dilate+Erode`) to improve your target blobs
6. Get outer contours (ignore inner contours)
7. Convert these contours to `bounding rectangles`
8. Get two `bounding rectangles` properties: `aspect ratio` and `area`
9. Filter your bounding rectangle according to threshold properties values

Let's see the code:

```
# importing cv2 and numpy:
import numpy as np
import cv2

# image path
path = "C://opencvImages//"
fileName = "board.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# Convert the image to HSV:
frame_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Prepare a dictionary to store the lower and upper
# HSV thresholds:
rangeDictionary = {}

# brown color
lower_values = np.array([6, 63, 0])
upper_values = np.array([23, 255, 81])

# push it into the dictionary:
rangeDictionary[0] = (lower_values, upper_values, "brown")

# gray color
lower_values = np.array([23, 0, 0])
upper_values = np.array([80, 105, 107])

# push it into the dictionary:
rangeDictionary[1] = (lower_values, upper_values, "gray")

# white color
lower_values = np.array([37, 0, 131])
upper_values = np.array([170, 25, 152])

# push it into the dictionary:
rangeDictionary[2] = (lower_values, upper_values, "white")

# Store results here:
targetRectangles = []
```

So far I have [looked up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469394/opencv-choosing-hsv-thresholds-for-color-filtering) the `HSV` equivalents of the target colors. I have defined `upper` and `lower` thresholds for these colors and store 'em inside a `dictionary`. The idea is to loop through this dictionary and extract each color range accordingly:

```
# Loop through the dictionary and locate each circle:
for i in rangeDictionary:

    # Get current lower and upper range values:
    current_LowRange = rangeDictionary[i][0]
    current_UppRange = rangeDictionary[i][1]

    # Create the HSV mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(frame_hsv, current_LowRange, current_UppRange)

    # Run a minimum area filter:
    minArea = 800
    mask = areaFilter(minArea, mask)
```

For the first color, this is the unfiltered binary mask:

[image]

You see here that I've implemented an `areaFilter`. This will get rid of blobs smaller than `800`, let's start cleaning your masks the proper way. This function is defined at the end of the post. What follows next is some `morphology` to further define the target blobs:

```
    # Pre-process mask:
    kernelSize = 3

    structuringElement = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))
    iterations = 10

    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, structuringElement, None, None, iterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, structuringElement, None, None, iterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
```

This is the filtered mask:

[image]

Very nice, eh? Nothing fancy, just a very aggressive `dilation + erosion` chain. I want to define the pucks nice and clean. Depending on the size of your input image you might need to tweak the `iterations` value. Let's continue. The following step (still inside the loop) is to compute `contours` (only the outer ones) and approximate each `contour` as a `polygon` and, then, as a `rectangle`:

```
    # Find the big contours/blobs on the filtered image:
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # List to store all the bounding rectangles:
    contours_poly = [None] * len(contours)
    boundRect = []

    # Alright, just look for the outer bounding boxes:
    for b, c in enumerate(contours):

        if hierarchy[0][b][3] == -1:

            # Approximate the contour to a polygon:
            contours_poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
            # Convert the polygon to a bounding rectangle:
            boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(contours_poly)
```

Now we are dealing with `bounding rectangles` and the operations get much straightforward. Let's get the dimensions of the rectangle and calculate a couple of parameters: `aspectRatio` and `area`. Using some heuristics, I've already set the minimum threshold values that will be used to filter the rectangles:

```
            # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
            rectX = boundRect[0]
            rectY = boundRect[1]
            rectWidth = boundRect[2]
            rectHeight = boundRect[3]

            rectArea = rectWidth * rectHeight

            # Calculate the aspect ratio:
            aspectRatio = rectWidth / rectHeight
            delta = abs(1.0 - aspectRatio)

            # Set the min threshold values to identify the
            # blob of interest:
            minArea = 1000
            epsilon = 0.2

            # Is this bounding rectangle one the one we
            # are looking for?
            if rectArea > minArea and delta < epsilon:

                # Set a color:
                color = (0, 255, 0)
                inputCopy = inputImage.copy()

                # Draw the current rectangle on a copy of the BGR input:
                cv2.rectangle(inputCopy, (int(rectX), int(rectY)),
                              (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(rectY + rectHeight)), color, 2)
                # Store this bounding rectangle:
                targetRectangles.append(boundRect)


                # Label the current mask:
                currentColor = rangeDictionary[i][2]

                org = (rectX, rectY -10)
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                color = (255, 0, 0)
                cv2.putText(inputCopy, currentColor, org, font,
                            0.5, color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

                cv2.imwrite(path + "colorMask_"+currentColor+".png", inputCopy)
```

I've additionally drawn the target rectangle on a deep copy of the input and drawn nice text to identify the color, check out the results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

*"B-b-but man, what about the black puck?!"* Well, I had to left something for you to do. If you have followed until now, it should be easy to get the additional mask. This is the definition and implementation of the `areaFilter` function:

```
def areaFilter(minArea, inputImage):

    # Perform an area filter on the binary blobs:
    componentsNumber, labeledImage, componentStats, componentCentroids = \
    cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(inputImage, connectivity=4)

    # Get the indices/labels of the remaining components based on the area stat
    # (skip the background component at index 0)
    remainingComponentLabels = [i for i in range(1, componentsNumber) if componentStats[i][4] >= minArea]

    # Filter the labeled pixels based on the remaining labels,
    # assign pixel intensity to 255 (uint8) for the remaining pixels
    filteredImage = np.where(np.isin(labeledImage, remainingComponentLabels) == True, 255, 0).astype('uint8')

    return filteredImage
```

Damn, looking at all that, I probably should be acknowledged somewhere in your project report. Hope you find this information useful.

Comment: That's a beautiful answer, thanks a lot. I will test the solution tomorrow and choose this answer. Also i saw that u tested on the wrong image ( the cropped one that was showing the result). I will test it on the first picture ( world view) haha i guess i will only have to play with the upper/lower bound. The dilate/erode method seems awesome will make the detection way more easy. Thanks a lot i'll come back tomorrow to test it :)

Comment: out of curiosity, i checkout the result mask for black color with those values : lower_values = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_values = np.array([179,255,20]) and the circle seems pretty clear, but somehow it's never detected, any reasons why ? thanks a lot :) (tried on the big picture)

Comment: @codejourney Maybe the area of the circle falls below the minimum threshold, which is defined in `minArea`. Try to tweak this setting. Now, the **aspect ratio** (`width/height`) is also important. The pucks are circular, which means they must exhibit an aspect ratio close to `1` (same width and same height) if the (segmented) puck is too irregular, the aspect ratio might fall outside (a little bit) of the expected value. Tweak the variable `epsilon` to allow a more relaxed threshold.