# How to detect a precise rectangle in a photo opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I was using this code to detect the rectangle on the photo, at first it was working well, untill i realized that i would have an object that is also a square in the middle :

**Question:**

How can i properly detect the 4 corners like on the first result picture without detecting the corner of the thing in the middle of the square. Thanks a lot.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = cv2.imread('Photos/lastBoard.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 200)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 25, 0.01, 50)

corner_list = []
for corner in corners:
    x, y = corner.ravel()

    if(y < 700 and (50 < x < 800 )):
        corner_list.append([int(x), int(y)])
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 5, (36, 255, 12), -1)

cv2.imshow("yo", img)


cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My man, it breaks my heart you aren't using the techniques and processing we covered in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66287190/how-to-accurately-detect-brown-black-grey-white-on-this-picture-with-opencv/66288066#66288066). You have already plenty of functions you could re-use. The rectangle you are trying to segment has a **unique color** (kind of green) and has a **defined area** and **aspect ratio**! Look all the things you have on the table, they are smaller than the rectangle! Plus, the rectangle is almost a square! That means that its aspect ratio is close to `1.0`. If you somehow segment the rectangle, approximating its corners should be relativity easy.

This is valuable info, because it allows you to trace your action plan. I see you are using `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` to detect the corners of everything. That's OK, but it could be simplified. I propose a plan of action very similar to last time:

1. Try to **segment** the rectangle using its color, let's compute an
   `HSV`-based mask
2. Let's clean the mask from noise using an **area filter** and some **morphology**
3. Find `contours` - we are looking for the biggest green `contour`, the rectangle.
4. The **contour of interest** has defined features. Use the `area` and `aspect ratio` to filter garbage contours.
5. Once you have the contour/blob of interest, **approximate** its corners.

Let's see the code:

```
# imports:
import numpy as np
import cv2

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "table1.jpg"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)
inputCopy = inputImage.copy()

# The HSV mask values:
lowerValues = np.array([58, 151, 25])
upperValues = np.array([86, 255, 75])

# Convert the image to HSV:
hsvImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Create the HSV mask
mask = cv2.inRange(hsvImage, lowerValues, upperValues)
```

The first steps aim to create the `HSV` mask. Very similar to last time, I've defined the `HSV` range of interest already and applied exactly the same stuff as before. You could (and should) explore more exotic techniques latter, but let's stick with what we know works for the time being, as the project surely is due soon. This is the result:

[image]

You see how the mask is pretty nice already? Only the green puck and the rectangle survived the `thresholding`. It doesn't matter that the rectangle is not complete, because we're gonna approximate its contour with a `bounding rectangle`! Alright, let's clean this bad boy a little bit better. Use a `filterArea` (this is exactly the same function we saw last time) and then a `closing` (`dilate` followed by `erode`) just to get a nice mask:

```
# Run a minimum area filter:
minArea = 50
mask = areaFilter(minArea, mask)

# Pre-process mask:
kernelSize = 3

structuringElement = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))
iterations = 2

mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, structuringElement, None, None, iterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, structuringElement, None, None, iterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
```

This is the filtered mask, the noise is mostly gone:

[image]

Now, let's find `contours` and **filtered** based on `area` and `aspect ratio`, just like last time. The parameters, however, are different, because our target is not the plucks, but the rectangle:

```
# Find the big contours/blobs on the filtered image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Store the poly approximation and bound
contoursPoly = [None] * len(contours)

# Store the corners of the square here:
detectedCorners = []

# Look for the outer bounding boxes:
for _, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Approximate the contour to a polygon:
    contoursPoly = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)

    # Convert the polygon to a bounding rectangle:
    boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(contoursPoly)

    # Get the bounding rect's data:
    rectX = boundRect[0]
    rectY = boundRect[1]
    rectWidth = boundRect[2]
    rectHeight = boundRect[3]

    # Calculate the rect's area:
    rectArea = rectWidth * rectHeight

    # Calculate the aspect ratio:
    aspectRatio = rectWidth / rectHeight
    delta = abs(1.0 - aspectRatio)

    # Set the min threshold values to identify the
    # blob of interest:
    minArea = 2500
    epsilon = 0.2
```

Alright, so far so good, I hope. As you see I *approximated* the contour to a 4-vertex polygon and then computed its `bounding rectangle`. This approximation should fit very nicely to our blob of interest. Now, apply the contour filter and use the bounding rectangle data to approximate the corners. I approximate each corner, one by one, and store them in the
`detectedCorners` array. Then, we can draw 'em. Here, still inside the `for` loop:

```
    # Is this bounding rectangle we
    # are looking for?
    if rectArea > minArea and delta < epsilon:

        # Compute the corners/vertices:
        # Corner 1 (top left)
        corner1 = (rectX, rectY)
        detectedCorners.append(corner1)
        # Corner 2 (top right)
        corner2 = (rectX + rectWidth, rectY)
        detectedCorners.append(corner2)
        # Corner 3 (bottom left)
        corner3 = (rectX, rectY + rectHeight)
        detectedCorners.append(corner3)
        # Corner 4 (bottom right)
        corner4 = (rectX + rectWidth, rectY + rectHeight)
        detectedCorners.append(corner4)

        # Draw the corner points:
        for p in detectedCorners:
            color = (0, 0, 255)
            cv2.circle(inputCopy, (p[0], p[1]), 5, color, -1)
            cv2.imshow("Square Corners", inputCopy)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here are the results for both images. The approximated corners are the red dots:

[image]
[image]

Here's the definition and implementation of the `areaFilter` function:

```
def areaFilter(minArea, inputImage):

    # Perform an area filter on the binary blobs:
    componentsNumber, labeledImage, componentStats, componentCentroids = \
cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(inputImage, connectivity=4)

    # Get the indices/labels of the remaining components based on the area stat
    # (skip the background component at index 0)
    remainingComponentLabels = [i for i in range(1, componentsNumber) if componentStats[i][4] >= minArea]

    # Filter the labeled pixels based on the remaining labels,
    # assign pixel intensity to 255 (uint8) for the remaining pixels
    filteredImage = np.where(np.isin(labeledImage, remainingComponentLabels) == True, 255, 0).astype('uint8')

    return filteredImage
```

Comment: i shouldve thought about it haha, i have a question coming back to the puck problem of last time, the solution seems to depend a lot on the condition of the lights ( for the colors). Do you think cv2.matchTemplate is a more robust solution to the puck color problem ? Thanks :D

Comment: @codejourney Template Match is typically helpful when you need to match shapes. Maybe you can use it, but it depends a lot on the shape you are trying to match (in this case, circles – and how you get those circles from segmented masks) and their size (the shapes have to be roughly the same size). What you might need to include is a more robust segmentation technique that handles light variation. Maybe you can normalize light conditions across your frames try contrast equalization or maybe gamma correction. I’d suggest researching that topic. Good luck, man.

Comment: cool one last question if possible haha, if i want the interior corners of the square is it possible also with this code ? ( I'm not sure what to adjust) i tried with area but no luck THANKS

Comment: @codejourney You will need to add further code to get the inner corners. In this case, the rectangle is not completely segmented – there’s a gap at the top, due to lightning noise, so you get one contour instead of two (i.e., the inner and outer contour), so the solution is not straightforward. One (dirty) way to get the inner corners might be by cropping the segmented binary mask (with the coordinates you already got), inverting the mask and looking again for contours - this will now get you the inner contour. Then, get the bounding rectangle and approximate corners just like before.